# User frequently comments about a pet issue with questionable relevance

Tags: discussion

Months ago, a user had the habit of writing comments on any pyqt question or related topics, comments similar to the following:

> First I would warn you that using super( ) in Python introduces 4
>   known issues that must be handled properly as well as bugs. For while
>   super( ) works fine in C++ it does not work as seamlessly in Python
>   due to the major differences between these 2 languages. If you cannot
>   find this information I can share it but I just thought I would let
>   you know. Of course using the basic explicit method does not cause
>   these issues and is as just as simple as using super( ) further you do
>   not actually gain anything useful using super( ) in Python that could
>   not be done in a much safer manner.

It could be interesting if the cause of the problem or the issue had to do with using "super", but it's not since he does it indiscriminately. It's uncomfortable seeing the same comments on many questions. They're distracting.

At first I tried asking him not to post these comments. Despite many requests he didn't stop. He didn't seem to understand.

Then I chose to raise a flag for a moderator to deal with it. It seems like something happened as the comments stopped. (I don't know if he was suspended?) But a few weeks later it started up again. I resumed raising flags and the moderators eliminated those comments. I also raised a personalized flag given the repeated attitude.

In addition to the repetitive comment above he also wrote the following aggressive comment:

> There are also further issues sprinkled through that example and I can
>   help you them and this issue but that would require more interaction
>   than posting a comment -- and due to Trolls on this forum I will not
>   post an answer anymore -- so if you would like more extensive help
>   with this and are comfortable with doing so just a leave a way to
>   contact you here and I will reach out to you or you can contact me
>   either would work

That comment could have two consequences:

- It might give the OP (and any reader) a negative view of the community, and
- It might stop people from giving feedback when someone asks the OP for more information since it indicates that they are contacted by other means. That would lead to questions without answers, or questions with problems that cannot be reproduced.

As he points out, it is a repetitive behavior. A simple flag does not seem to solve it. So my question is: What's the next step?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a flag would have worked to solve the problem with the second quoted comment. If it didn't, some moderator was asleep at the wheel. For the first comment, meh. It's a comment. My biggest complaint with it is that it implies using `super()` is somehow reasonable in C++. It isn't. **If the sheer volume of repetitive comments is the issue, don't flag individual comments**: flag the post with a custom moderator flag and explain the problem plainly.

Comment: @CodyGray Both comments have been resolved with individual flags (and I thank the moderators for their time to do so), but I also wrote a custom flag explaining the repetitive action of 1) repetitive comments that are unnecessary and 2) aggressive comments, and the moderator removed the comments but it seems that I do not treat the underlying problem: That the action has become a habit for the user.

Comment: @CodyGray I thought the flag in the post was to point out the inappropriate content of the post and not the comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, we are aware of the issues surrounding this user, and we have been handling those flags and communicating with the user about what specifically is an issue and what isn't.

> A simple flag does not seem to solve it

Those flags do help to solve issues like these, because that gives us at least a picture of the impact their behaviour is having on others using the site.

It *may* be more helpful to flag one post (your own, one of theirs, or a post they commented on) and summarise, as objectively as you can, what you have observed and provide evidence. Including pointers to where you asked them to stop are helpful too. A single custom flag can be more effective than flagging repeated comments. Yes, custom flags can be used this way, they don't *have* to be about a problem with the flagged post for cases like these, and we can respond to post flags with custom responses.

*Usually*, problematic behaviour like this stops after we talk to the user. Sometimes, however, someone *doesn't* stop, and so you may see the same behaviour continue for longer, or return after a break. Just use a new flag if sufficient time has passed (at least a few days), we can't always handle flags immediately.

Try not to engage the user about the behaviour again though, if they haven't been responsive to moderator intervention they may well react badly to community members trying to intervene some more.

Comment: What happens if the user does not stop? I imagine this is not the first time you guys have to deal with something like this.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Moderator options for that are [outlined in the Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct); after warnings, the next step is [account suspension](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay, I thought that the post flags only served to point out the post's problems, and the comment flags are for the post's problems, but it seems that is not the case. Well, it seems great to me that they are analyzing the behavior of that user and hopefully they take the necessary actions to avoid that type of behavior.  It should only be noted that in one of my flags (after a dozen flags) I pointed out: *This user comments the same thing in several posts(which is often annoying and insulting). I have already reported it for months and it seems that it was suspended.*